# Flip animation based on scroll position

Tags: javascript

This is a follow-on from this question: [Animation based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813669/animation-based-on-scroll-position)

The goal is to loop through each element, and change it's rotation and perspective based on the users scroll position. I guess from an organic UX viewpoint, you'd want the top of the browser window to 'squash' the topmost item, and smoothy flip the element down.

Here's a screenshot for guidance:
[image: screenshot]

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfquerido/0zpc2a76/

And the loop function:

```
var _items = function () {

  forEach(items, function (item) {

    var scrollTop = _scrollTop(),
      elementTop = item.offsetTop,
      documentHeight = _getDocumentHeight(),

      // Transform the item based on scroll
      rotationFactor =  Math.max(0, scrollTop - elementTop),
      perspectiveFactor =  Math.max(0, scrollTop - elementTop),
      rotation = (rotationFactor / (documentHeight - windowHeight) * 90),
      perspective = (perspectiveFactor / (documentHeight - windowHeight) * 2000),
      transform = 'perspective(' + perspective + ') rotateX(' + rotation + 'deg)';

    // Elements off the top edge.
    if(scrollTop > elementTop) {
      item.classList.add('scrolling');
      item.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('scrolling');
      item.style.webkitTransform = null; // Reset the transform
    }

  });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0zpc2a76/1/

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are trying to get the blue boxes to "fold over" as if they are being pushed down by the top of the viewport. For that, your calculations seem to be wrong, so I updated some of the variable assignments:

```
rotation = (rotationFactor / (item.offsetHeight) * 90),
perspective = 2000 - (perspectiveFactor / (item.offsetHeight) * 2000),
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a million @Quantastical. Working out some animation details, but the actual implementation on the actual project I'm working on looks great.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for turning this into an infinite carousel? Do I remove the top element once it's out of view and append it at the bottom of the list?

Comment: So you want the items to loop back around? If so, yeah, probably remove the top element and append it to the bottom. You might have to update the scrollTop back to 0 when you do that. I can't tell off the top of my head what effects it might have on the scroll position as you mess about with the DOM.